# Some pages not passed to app server by Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I set up nginx as a reverse proxy to Thin Rails app server.

```
server {
    listen 82;
    server_name www.hamburgers.com;
    root /var/user_cases/user_00001/user_case_11/public;
    location ~\.* {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

some pages open, see `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2012:18:33:53 +0400] "GET /assets/e.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.hamburgers.com:82/user_session/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2012:18:34:01 +0400] "POST /user_session HTTP/1.1" 302 113 "http://www.hamburgers.com:82/user_session/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"
```

but some fail with such record in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2012/05/28 18:34:03 [error] 5710#0: *117 open() "/var/www/nginx-default/user_cases" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /user_cases HTTP/1.1", host: "www.hamburgers.com", referrer: "http://www.hamburgers.com:82/user_session/new"
```

I suppose nginx for some reason uses `/var/www/nginx-default` instead of `www.humburgers.com` for some pages. I've no clue why.

**How can I fix that?**

Comment: redirect_to :controller=>...,:action => ...

causes the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found solution. I should use

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

instead of

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```